# What is the proper way to handle errors?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a little stuck on something, I have this PHP code here which is inside my file api.php:

```
try {
    $test = "testt";
    if ($test == "test") {
        echo json_encode('success');
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Condition wrong');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
```

and I am calling api.php via Jquery ajax like so:

```
var data = $('#form').serialize();
$.ajax({url: "api.php", dataType: "json", data: data, type: "POST", 
success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
},
error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(textStatus);
}});
```

The problem I am having is: error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) is not being called. Do I want to throw another exception on my catch instead of json_encode like so:

`throw new Exception($e->getMessage());` instead of `echo json_encode($e->getMessage());`

Throwing 2 Exceptions that have the same message look weird to me. The goal is, if there is an exception thrown, catch and print it on my ajax error call, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Probably get closed as opinion based but personally I always successfully (by using `try/catch`) return JSON e.g. `{ "status" : "success", ... }` or `{ "status" : "error", ... }` from my PHP and then check `result.status` in the `success` function

Comment: Trying that now, but I get an error on this, I am probably doing something stupid here: `echo json_encode({"status" : "success"});`

Comment: Yeah it should be `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));`

Comment: @user979331 Did the answers help you at all? Feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your error function never gets called is that the `http response status code` from the request will still be `200 (OK)` (because the exception has been caught). Set the `http_response_code` explicitly:

```
try {
    if (false)
        echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
    else
        throw new Exception('Condition wrong');

} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode(['success'=>false, 'message'=>$e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Any value in the range of 400 to 599 should make the error function to be called. See [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).